# "Pokerole RPG tools" companion software missing

Tags: tools, pokerole

I have been using a companion app for the pokerole rule system (A fanmade rule system for running games in the pokemon universe) called "pokerole RPG tools" that has been incredibly helpful, but it seems to be missing from the windows 10 app store (and android store) at the moment.

The official website and forums for the rulesystem have no information on the subject, not even acknowledging that it's no longer available. Has there been an update as to why it's missing? It's been incredibly helpful for me as a GM, but I lost my installation in a PC reset.

Comment: Welcome to site! Take the [tour]. You've my sympathy in your plight—it always sucks to lose a valuable tool. I hope that since the official Web site and the official forums were unhelpful that someone on this site can offer a reason why the application is no longer available. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: (Note that *Pokerole* is a real role-playing game about which the site has fielded questions. Further, note that the asker isn't interested in *acquiring* the application but is only wondering *why* the application is no longer available. Because of this, while the question is both timely and unusual, I think it remains on topic for the site. Whether or not users can *answer* the question is beside the point.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thanks for the comment, I concur.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is similar to design-intent questions and should be off topic for reasons [similar to these](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7917/42865). In particular, the question "why is this tool missing" isn't about the actual problem, a question like "how can I do X without this missing tool" might be more on-topic

Comment: @Ruse Vote your conscience, man, but I think it's closer to a question like [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/24967/8610), [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11542/8610), and [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/11076/8610). When something goes missing, folks want to know why, and often the site will provide.

Comment: @HeyICanChan those questions are indeed very similar, but they are already frased better. "What happened to X" involves less intent than "why did X go missing". But even then, the only satifying answers to those questions required the creators of those tool to personally explain what happened, which is another way in which these questions are similar to design-intent questions. And case in point, 2/3 of the accepted answers to the questions you linked were alegedly posted by people who worked on the missing tools.

Comment: @Ruse Fair enough. In addition to your close vote, I urge you to take those feelings about this to Meta and pitch to the community closing new questions like this generally. Questions like this have a longstanding history on the site.